# How can i mirror live streaming youtube video

Tags: video, youtube, video-streaming, youtube-data-api, hint

There are youtube streamers, that have a few of views, i want to help them out.
I want to be able to mirror a live streaming video on my own channel in "featured" pane. How can i do it? 
Standardly i can put a url link to a video *currently* being streamed, but it would aftertime end, and i would have to add other url of a currently live streaming manually. 
I would want to put some kind of code to ***automatically** pick a live streaming video*.
The code could do such: login in my youtube account, detect a live stream on a specified channel, copy url address into "For returning subscribers".
Help!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

[How to embed new Youtube's live video permanent URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39275889/how-to-embed-new-youtubes-live-video-permanent-url)

As @audiomason said:

> The embed URL for a channel's live stream is:
>
> `https://www.youtube.com/embed/live_stream?channel=CHANNEL_ID`
>
> You can find your CHANNEL_ID at https://www.youtube.com/account_advanced

Comment: what if i want to use someone else CHANNEL_ID?

Comment: When you visit someone's channel, the url would look something like: 
https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCKkAl9IwAt2rIyonJvm8nZZ 
_UCKkAl9IwAt2rIyonJvm8nZZ_ is his/her channel id.

Comment: this is not answering the question per se.