# Permanent Stream Now link for embedding 2019/2020

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, live-streaming, youtube-livestreaming-api

I've found multiple links to embed YouTube livestreams across Stack:

`https://www.youtube.com/embed/live_stream?channel={CHANNEL_ID}`
`https://www.youtube.com/channel/{ChannelID}/live`

But no one works when I use my correct channel id. It looks like YouTube doesn't support permanent links for unlisted live streams anymore. Can anyone confirm this, or does it still exist?

Or can I use the YouTube API to know what the next Stream Now video id is going to be. That could also solve my problems. However, up until now I haven't found a way to retrieve this data.

P.s. Our stream must be **UNLISTED**. We don't want to stream publicly.

Comment: I think the this link (`https://www.youtube.com/embed/live_stream?channel={CHANNEL_ID}`) will only work if you set the live stream to public as per comment in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39582176/8342742). Also, you can find enough information from the documentation of [YouTube API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/getting-started).