# Embedded YouTube Livestream Stopped Functioning

Tags: iframe, youtube, embed, live-streaming

So, I had my organization's permanent livestream embedded on one of our web pages using the advice I found here ([How to embed new Youtube's live video permanent URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39275889/how-to-embed-new-youtubes-live-video-permanent-url/39582176#39582176)), and it was working great for a few months, with the current live stream playing, then the next scheduled one replacing that after that one ended.

Here is what I was using:

```
<iframe width="100%" height="500" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/live_stream?channel=<<CHANNEL_ID>>;autoplay=1" title="" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture; web-share" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Unfortunately, at some point in the last few days, it stopped working and the "This video is unavailable" error message.

I checked and the streams are set to public, and the embed video box is checked in the settings.  I can embed the scheduled live stream videos individually, and link to the channel, but not to the permanent live stream like before.

Basically, I am wondering if anyone might have any ideas as to what is going on.  Did YouTube change something or is there another setting I should check? Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I am experiencing the same issues too! One quick workaround I found is that you can embed scheduled live streams one at a time until YT gets this fixed.

Comment: Yep, that is what we are doing at the moment.  Hopefully this is a temporary issue, not a permanent change because the way it worked before was a million times better.